# How to query from nested Json array object where there are multiple sub arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve from a subarray of JSON object where "menuId": "AOIEnquiryActivity" and "isEnabled": "yes". Here I have query in PostgreSQL.

```
[
  {
    "menuId": "",
    "menuText": "Service Request",
    "menuIcon": "vector_ic_agent_tools",
    "isEnabled": "Yes",
    "subMenu": [
      {
        "menuId": "",
        "menuText": "Customer Tools",
        "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
        "isEnabled": "Yes",
        "subMenu": [
          {
            "menuId": "AOIEnquiryActivity",
            "menuText": "AOI Update Request",
            "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
            "isEnabled": "yes",
            "subMenu": []
          },
          {
            "menuId": "SearchByCASAAccForLoanActivity",
            "menuText": "Loan Request",
            "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
            "isEnabled": "No",
            "subMenu": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the output/result you want?

Comment: Get the list for menuId = AOIEnquiryActivity where isEnabled = yes.

Comment: The whole row of the table? A single column for each row containing the array from the JSON key?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query('[
  {
    "menuId": "",
    "menuText": "Service Request",
    "menuIcon": "vector_ic_agent_tools",
    "isEnabled": "Yes",
    "subMenu": [
      {
        "menuId": "",
        "menuText": "Customer Tools",
        "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
        "isEnabled": "Yes",
        "subMenu": [
          {
            "menuId": "AOIEnquiryActivity",
            "menuText": "AOI Update Request",
            "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
            "isEnabled": "yes",
            "subMenu": []
          },
          {
            "menuId": "SearchByCASAAccForLoanActivity",
            "menuText": "Loan Request",
            "menuIcon": "vector_ic_new_account",
            "isEnabled": "No",
            "subMenu": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]' :: jsonb, '$.** ? (@.menuId == "AOIEnquiryActivity" && @.isEnabled == "yes")')
LIMIT 1
```

but be carreful of the lower/upper case in your json keys and values ("yes" is different from "Yes")

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c2a53094bfdea0e620df4e0f39f3243d)